# Passing unicode via aiohttp url

Tags: python, python-3.6, aiohttp

I am trying to make asynchronous GET function, but when url contains unicode(i used Korean letter) string, it occurs `400 Bad Request`. There is no problem when i use requests, but only aiohttp gives me an error. How can i handle this problem?

**requests**

```
import requests

def get():
    response = requests.get("some url with unicode")
    return response

get()    # 200 OK
```

**aiohttp**

```
import asyncio
import aiohttp

async def get():
    response = await aiohttp.request("GET", "some url with unicode")
    return response

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(get())    # 400 Bad Request
```

I am using `Python 3.6`, `asyncio 3.4.3`, `aiohttp 1.0.5`.

Comment: URLs cannot contain non-ASCII characters, you should be URL-encoding anything else beforehand.

Comment: I printed my url containing unicode, and it has form of `"\ud504\ub9b0\ud2b8"`. What is the expected form of encoded unicode?

Comment: There is no single universal serialization format for URLs. Maybe examine what `requests` does. I would guess that it encodes the string as UTF-8 and then URL-encodes the result; so something like `"%ed%94%84%eb%a6%b0%ed%8a%b8"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found solution myself.

```
from urllib import parse

url = "some url with unicode"
parsed = parse.urlparse(url)
parsed = parse.parse_qs(parsed.query)
encoded = parse.urlencode(parsed, doseq=True)
url = "{}?{}".format("url base without parameters", encoded)
```

Then `url` is encoded ascii string, and i got `200 OK`. Thanks for comments :)